# Linear Feedback Shift Register algorithm

Tags: matlab, xor, bit-shift

I'm trying to code my own implementation of Linear Feedback Shift Register on Matlab in order to generate a pseudo-random sequence of numbers. Suppose I need to generate a sequence from 1 to 16,384 (2^14) in random order, my initial state is number 329 and the tap is 7.

This is the code I've got so far:

```
function [rndV] = lfsr(limit, init, tap)
    X = -1;
    rndV = init;
    bits = nextpow2(limit);
    while(X ~= init)
        if(X == -1)
            X = init;
        end
        a = bitget(X, bits);
        b = bitget(X, tap);
        X = bitshift(X,1,bits);
        X = bitset(X,1,bitxor(a,b));
        rndV = [rndV X];
    end
end
```

The parameters are:

```
limit = 16,384
init = 329
tap = 7
```

If I get right LFSR, must the algorithm loop until the initial state is found again? Does this loop must generate all numbers between 1 and 16,384 in random order?

Something is wrong on my code or maybe I misunderstood LFSR algorithm, but I'm getting just 22 numbers in random order, then the initial state (329) is found again.

I want to achieve the same as described [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall08/cos126/assignments/lfsr.html) but in matlab.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

only a primitive polynomial can got full range of random numbers. check [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvYtZsho-JTldFRYZnJLRFFaSWtUcVNXc1Y3M2VWd1E&hl=en#gid=0) for primpolyes, or [here](http://www.seanerikoconnor.freeservers.com/Mathematics/AbstractAlgebra/PrimitivePolynomials/theory.html) if you need bigger order of LSFR